# English word for a contest where participants collect items

Tags: single-word-requests

Well, I'm hoping that the title is self-explanatory. I'm looking for a word (or a Wikipedia article) that describes the type of competition where participants are encouraged to buy more products, and accidentally collect tokens. These tokens are understood to be worth something in tandem.

Comment: I think you mean *incidentally* collect tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an "On-Pack Coupon Promotion", or simply an "On-Pack Promotion".